# Does InstanceCount=1 in ServiceFabric mean 'at least one instance' or 'no more than one instance'?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, redundancy

Does `InstanceCount=1` in ServiceFabric mean 'at least one instance' or 'no more than one instance'? From the documentation I've seen it's unclear and I have a scenario where I want at most one instance of my application running at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-model-schema-elements.md) by *tomvcassidy* Instance Count=1 in Service Fabric means at least one instance

When `InstanceCount` is set to 1, it means that exactly one instance of the service will be created and running at any given moment.  In order to keep the desired instance count of 1 if the instance fails or removed, Service Fabric will automatically create a new instance.

If you want to ensure that at most one instance of your application is running at any one time, you can set the `InstanceCount` property to 1.

This configuration ensures that only one instance of the service is running, and if that instance fails or is removed, Service Fabric will automatically create a new instance to maintain the desired count of 1.

Comment: Your answer seems to be conflicting: _InstanceCount=1 means at **least** one_ **vs** _InstanceCount=1 means at **most** one_

Comment: When InstanceCount is set to 1 it means that exactly one instance of the service will be created running at any given moment. If you want to ensure that at most one instance of your application is running at any one time, you can set the InstanceCount property to 1.

Comment: The first line of your answer says 'Instance Count=1 in Service Fabric means **at least one** instance' though. Was this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

When setting the instance count to 1, it means that **eventually** the service would have only 1 instance, but there may be cases, especially during service startup that you will have more than 1 instance. Therefore its not 'no more than one instance on any given time'
Personally I have seen cases where a service would startup and it was running on all nodes for a few seconds until the cluster honored the instance count and placement constraints and eventually reduced the instance count as configured.
If you are trying to use this functionality to implement a business logic that has to run at most once on any given time, you should implement a distributed lock in your logic as well (e.g. use Azure blob storage lease).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.description.statelessservicedescription.instancecount?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Do you have any documentation on where 'especially during service startup' you'd see more than one instance? The only docs I can find say that the InstanceCount defines how many copies are created:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-scalability#:~:text=InstanceCount%20defines%20how%20many%20running%20copies%20of%20that%20service%27s%20code%20are%20created%20when%20the%20service%20starts%20up.

Comment: nope, I've only seen this behavior on my own cluster. If you need more accurate answer that is backed up by docs, i suggest opening a support case on the Azure Portal and ask them to clarify the docs as well.